# How to use binding without using raw() method?

Tags: javascript, oracle, knex.js, objection.js

I am new to knexjs.

Knexjs: Binding with raw() works great. Is it possible to use binding with SQL builder without using the raw() method?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of how you are using raw?

Comment: knex.raw(
`insert into logger (LOG_NAME, TRAN_DATE, TRAN_TYPE, LOG_DETAIL, UID)
 select ?, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?
 from sys.dual`,
 [logName, tranType, JSON.stringify(logData), uid])
.then()

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to use `knex.raw()` but you don't have to write all query as single raw query. You can do only part of the query as raw like this:

```
  knex('table').where(knex.raw('lower(??)', ['firstName']), 'mikael')
```

Comment: what is the difference between ?? and ? for bind variables?

Comment: `??` is identifier replacement, which is used for quoting identifiers like `TableName.columnName` properly in a case sensitive manner. So those replacements are rendered directly to the SQL string which is set to a driver to be executed. `?` is used for value literals.